# How to call title attribute enable from screen options in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

enter code hereI have adding title with menu from screen options in wordpress. Trying to call title dynamic in wordpress but not getting any solutions.
html code :

Home

Wp dynamic code :
wp_list_pages(array( 'title_li'=>'','include'=> array( 5 )));

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a function named get_current_screen you can use it like this :

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
$option = $screen->get_option('name_of_your_option', 'option');
```

Comment: I want to display in frontend menu in anchor tag like < a href="" title="title_attribute_value">

Comment: In this case you should use walker menu in your wp_nav_menu like 'walker' => new my_custom_Walker()